# Can't see logs in Developer Console

Tags: developer-console

Why My Developer Console showing like this, in my developer console i am not able to see the logs, what i want to do.

[image: Developer Console]

Comment: I suspect you might have finished up API calls .

Comment: @sagar What i want to do now.Any Suggestions

Comment: You have the "Command Line" open, which is blocking the log panel. Press Ctrl+Shift+L to close it. Then, click on the bottom header that says "Logs, Tests, and Problems to open it. If you still have trouble, you can also create a new workspace in the Workspace menu and switch to it.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a debug log?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Company Profile> Company Information and look for **API Requests, Last 24 Hours** if you have finished up them all , you need to wait for next 24 hours :<

Comment: it showing 200 but i have 5000 api request

Comment: Seems to be developer console bug. Try to check your logging levels selected or use Debug logs from the Salesforce Native UI.

Comment: i chaged Persepective Manager log level to true but no use.

Comment: Seems to be bug. Try native Debug logs its a same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually developer console is still under development we have seen some other issues alos during development so if you are getting any issues then take a breath and try to refresh the page or try after some time, you may also exceeded the API Limits only if you are getting a pop up 'Total Limit Exceeded' in the developer console.

Comment: it is happing for me last week onwards.